# Is there a simple input command in JavaScript like c++'s cin> >?

Tags: javascript, input

I want to know whether there is an input command in JavaScript like "cin>>" in C++ or the input in old Basic... because I need to ask the user to enter a word or a number on a web page and want to save that input into a variable and then print that variable using document.write(). There's the option of inputting through an input box in HTML and getting that input using document.getElementById and then writing that with the innerHTML element into a paragraph tag, but I just want to know if there's a simpler version available in js. Thanks.

Comment: [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)? But you don't want to use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write).

Comment: `var userInput = prompt("Please enter a value:")` to save the user's input into a variable. Then you can output that value in a myriad of different ways.

Comment: Do note that `prompt()` will return the user's entry as a string and you will need to use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` if you intend to use the value as a number.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your answers, it's been very helpful. This is how the piece of code I was looking for finally looks like:                                                 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body
<script>    
    var userInput = prompt ("Enter your name: ")
    document.write(userInput)
</script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is anything exactly like that in JS. But here is an example of the prompt function in Javascript.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_prompt

Comment: For technical details about `prompt` see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

Comment: I'm not sure that markdown works in comments @kuzyn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Answer (score 1):

Node JS have readline interface to do this, you can read it hear: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

With this document, you can input from console like c++ or java.
The code example:

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

  rl.close();
});
```

For more practice case, you can visit this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXaBeZ19RB4&t=329s

JS don't have friendly console input interface.